# What preparations had the Federation made to deal with the Borg before 'Best of Both Worlds Pt I'?

Tags: star-trek, borg, federation

In *Q, Who*, the Federation are first properly introduced to the Borg (they had been exposed to the Borg before, but not formally introduced shall we say).  When it came time a couple of years later when the Borg began their incursion into Federation space in *The Best of Both Worlds Pt I*, it was far sooner than the Federation had anticipated.  Shelby was assigned to the *Enterprise-D* as a Borg expert.  My question is, though, **what measures had the Federation taken in preparation to deal with the Borg threat before *The Best of Both Words Pt I***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific answers are hard to come by. [Shelby](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shelby):

> was placed in charge of Starfleet's defensive planning for a potential Borg invasion. Under the supervision of Admiral J.P. Hanson, Shelby proved the first who was able to put the project on a productive track. Thereafter, Hanson worked extremely closely with Shelby, spearheading all efforts to develop defenses against the Borg.

With The Borg's early arrival, they were [caught short](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/174.txt):

> Geordi in particular is stumped... moves to a monitor, presses panels that put up several design schemes...
>
> GEORDI: From what I've seen, I can't believe any of your new weapons systems can be ready in less than eighteen months, Commander.
>
> SHELBY (acknowledges) We've been projecting twenty-four.

This makes the nature of the preparation immaterial at that time. The best clue I can find to those preparations from after the fact is in the form of The USS Defiant, [which](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/447.txt)

> was designed for one purpose only -- to fight and defeat the Borg.

From the Defiant, and their effectiveness against the Borg sphere, we might assume that [quantum torpedoes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_torpedo) were amongst the preparations. Though The Defiant was commissioned without it, [ablative armor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ablative_armor) is a reasonable guess. Apart from that, more powerful versions of existing tactical systems would be a believable guess, to wit, The Defiant's phaser banks, which, if nothing else, looked really cool.

Comment: I believe the pulse phasers were new and introduced with the Defiant as well.

Comment: @BBlake Yes, and they looked really cool :-)